# Filter products depend on another ACTION in React-native Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have an app which get all categories and products from the server with **Redux ACTIONS**. I need to filter products with a category Id. after load data action is complete, i call another action to filter products but i'm a little bit confused.

There is codes of few parts of the app:

**ProductsActions:**

```
 export const GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA = "GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA";
 export const GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_RESULT = "GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_RESULT";  
 export const GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_ERROR = "GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_ERROR";  
 export const FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID = "FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID";

 export const getInitialProductsData = () => ({
       type: GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA
  });

 export const filterProductsByCategoryId = categoryId => ({
       type: FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID,
       categoryId
  });
```

**ProductsReducers:**

```
import {
  GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA,
  GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_RESULT,
  GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_ERROR,
  FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID
} from "../actions/products";

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  data: {},
  error: null
};

const filterProductsByCategoryId = (state, action) => {
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_RESULT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        data: action.result
      };
    case GET_INITIAL_PRODUCTS_DATA_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    case FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: filterProductsByCategoryId(state, action.categoryId)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

And there is my code to call filter action:

```
filterProducts = (title = "A") => {
const _categories = Object.values(this.props.categories);

const selectedCategory = _categories.find(
  category => category.title === title
);
this.props.dispatch(filterProductsByCategoryId(selectedCategory.id));
```

**My questions is:**
**A)** Is there is a way to filter my data and display them in UI and refresh them without using **ACTIONS** way??

**B)** If A's answer is No!, How can i get my state.data and filter them in **FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_ID**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return filtered result.
keep in mind that this will return an array and not a single value, which is a good thing if you are using this filter within your reducer. because your reducer's shape is an array and not an object.
Running example:

```js
const myData = [{
  name: 'some name',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'some name2',
  id: 2
}, {
  name: 'some name3',
  id: 3
}, {
  name: 'some name4',
  id: 4
}]

const filterProductsByCategoryId = (state, action) => {
 return state.filter(c => c.id === action.categoryId);
};

const result = filterProductsByCategoryId(myData, {categoryId: 2});
console.log(result);
```

I think it is more appropriate to create a [selector](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) for a singular product that will handle this kind of action, this way you will be able to return an object instead of an array with one product in it.
Not to mention the benefits of using [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to do some [memoizations](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html#creating-a-memoized-selector).
For this task you can use the [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const myData = [{
  name: 'some name',
  id: 1
}, {
  name: 'some name2',
  id: 2
}, {
  name: 'some name3',
  id: 3
}, {
  name: 'some name4',
  id: 4
}]

const filterProductsByCategoryId = (state, id) => {
 return state.find(c => c.id === id);
};

const result = filterProductsByCategoryId(myData, 2);
console.log(result);
```